# OpenLDAP Access handling

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP on Ubuntu Server 20.04. It works fine so far. Now I want to restrict access to the server, as by now anyone can read all entries e.g. in Thunderbird. Therefore I created a ldif file like this:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by * read
olcAccess: to * by * read
```

which is the standard configuration. Anyhow if I change the last entry to something else, e.g.

```
olcAccess: to * by users read
```

I cannot access LDAP in Thunderbird anymore. What I want is that Thunderbird asks for a username and password before it shows anything. In Thunderbird there are 5 fields to set:

```
Name              Any Name for the LDAP
Server address    DNS address
Base-DN           e.g. dc=example,dc=org   
Port-Number       636 
Bind-DN           ??
```

If i put nothing in the Bind-DN, Thunderbird does not ask for anything but also does not show anything. If I put my username or userid in it, it ask for a password but nothing is shown again.

I got two question:

- How should the ldif look like?
- What has to be put into Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2):

"Bind DN" is the name of a directory entry used in the login (bind) operation. In LDAP, there are no separate user IDs – instead your entries *themselves* are the LDAP accounts.

For example, `cn=Arne Fallisch,ou=Staff,dc=example,dc=org` would be your "Bind DN" (assuming it exists, of course), and the entry's `userPassword` attribute would be your password.

(The attribute can contain a hashed password; the `slappasswd` command can be used to generate a compatible password hash, or `ldappasswd` can be used to change the password online.)

Any entry regardless of its objectClass can be used for binding to the directory, as long as it has the userPassword attribute – this includes 'person', 'inetOrgPerson', 'posixAccount' and a few others.

---

Note that OpenLDAP ACLs work in "stealth" mode by default – that is, instead of saying "Access denied", the server pretends the unavailable entries don't exist at all. When protecting a whole server you probably would prefer it to just return an "Authentication is needed" error instead – to achieve this, define `olcRequires: bind authc` in your olcDatabase entry (but *not* in the global config entry; doing so would break things like StartTLS and SASL authentication).

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. I set up an ldif file with: 
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
An then put the bindDN to:
cn=Arne Fallisch,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
Then a password query appears but when I enter the password it pops up again or nothing happens. I also tried with uid=afallisch but it also does not work.
Interestingly I also use a NextCloud Server where the the connection works perfectly.

Comment: Forgot the "read" in the ldif file, no it works